# Clean code to be less messy

Tags: html, angularjs

Here's I am using simple form with angularjs. Everything works fine. I am having watchgroup for `EndDateFrom` & `EndDateTo` datepickers. When it's defined I am logging the value to console. I am constructing an expression based on my if conditions if value is defined from datepickers, But i feel my code is little messy. Is there any better way to format this to make more simple.

I know we can't use switch case for this, but just checking if there is any other way to make less messy

```
  $scope.$watchGroup(['$scope.EndDateFrom', '$scope.EndDateTo'], function () {

        if (!angular.isUndefined($scope.EndDateFrom) && !angular.isUndefined($scope.EndDateTo)) {

           return console.log(('expr://' + $filter('date')(new Date($scope.EndDateFrom), 'MM/dd/yyyy') + ' and ' + $filter('date')(new Date($scope.EndDateTo), 'MM/dd/yyyy')));
            // $scope.Test1 = 'expr://' + $filter('date')(new Date(disbursementsScheduleVm.processEndDateFrom), 'MM/dd/yyyy') + ' and ' + $filter('date')(new Date(disbursementsScheduleVm.processEndDateTo), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
        }
        else if(!angular.isUndefined($scope.EndDateFrom))
        {
            return console.log(('expr://' + $filter('date')(new Date($scope.EndDateFrom), 'MM/dd/yyyy')));
        }
        else if (!angular.isUndefined($scope.EndDateTo))
        {
            return console.log(('expr://' + $filter('date')(new Date($scope.EndDateTo), 'MM/dd/yyyy')));
        }

    });
```

Comment: compute each condition and result once, then produce the final result. anyways, this is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/